# How do edits work? Got 'Post deleted' for post that was not deleted

Tags: support, edits, voting, deleted-answers

The original question I saw this on is probably irrelevant (because it seems to have been a temporary thing), so I won't link to it, just describe what I saw. I was viewing a new question with a relatively simple answer. A new answer popped up while i was looking at it, so I refreshed & someone has posted a clever answer using sets.

Anyways, I go to vote the answer up, and get a red nastygram saying 'You can't do that, this post has been deleted'. Fine, it was a pretty simple question, that would be fast but maybe they deleted it or something.

Go back and the post hasn't been deleted - as far as I can tell, nothing is different, except the answer has been edited.

So: Does editing work by deleting and reinstating posts, and could it explain the weird error message I got?

Probably hard to reproduce - would have to hit the server at the right time - but it was strange.

Comment: Can you link to the post in question?

Comment: sure, it was this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543787/python-all-function-with-multiple-iterables. The answer doesn't show that it was edited, and I can't remember why i thought that now... i think that after I voted, I got a message telling me the answer had been modified and I needed to reload it. Maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You happened to click the vote arrow in a 5 seconds window in which the answer was deleted, as can be seen in its [revisions page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22543879/revisions):

> [image]

(as for edit, it was done during the 5 minutes grace period so it's not listed as a revision)

Comment: ok, so user error. i didn't even think to check that, but it probably should have been the first thing I looked at. i'll accept this as the answer as soon as it lets me. thanks!

Comment: No error, it's showing confirm dialog when trying to delete, more likely he intended to have it deleted while editing for some reason.

Comment: i meant, me the user with the error. everything working as intended.

Comment: Oh, lol! Yeah, all is good. :)